# Android App links does not work without user interaction from web

Tags: android

Below is my logic for App linking in Android.

Android Manifest :

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      <data android:scheme="https"
              android:host="www.payme.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/fundraiser/charity"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Web :

```
window.localtion.href = "https://www.payme.com/fundraiser/charity"
```

Issue here is when I app link on User Click such as button click or on hyperlink click, Its open up the Android App, but when I write the same logic i.e. from some API call back at run time in background, it does not open up the App, where I don't have user interaction.

Does chrome or Android blocks App link done in the background without user interactions? Any official document on this?

Comment: Can you tell me more(show some code) what you are doing in the background without user interaction  ?

Comment: i am reying to do  window.localtion.href = "https://www.payme.com/fundraiser/charity"  in call back

Comment: Can you try window.open("https://www.payme.com/fundraiser/charity", "_system")